# Sql Query with Parameters which might have value or can be null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table as follows:-

```
declare @table table(Inscode varchar(10), LocId varchar(10), effdate datetime)
insert into @table values('1','102','2023-02-01 00:00:00')
insert into @table values('1',NULL,NULL)

select * from @table
```

I am passing following parameters:-

```
declare @InsuranceCode VARCHAR(100)='1'
declare @LocationIds VARCHAR(100)=NULL
declare @EffectiveDate datetime='2023-02-01 00:00:00.000'
```

I want to built sql statement that is equivalent to

```
SELECT * from @table  where Inscode ='1' 
AND     LocId IS NULL
AND     effdate='2023-02-01 00:00:00.000'
```

My @LocationIds can have value or can be null, similarly @EffectiveDate can have value or can be null.
I tried following sql query, but I am not getting desired result

```
SELECT * from @table  where Inscode =@InsuranceCode 
AND     (LocId=@LocationIds OR LocId IS NULL)
AND     (effdate=@EffectiveDate OR effdate IS NULL)
```

Thank you

Comment: `Inscode in (@InsuranceCode) ` Why? `@InsuranceCode` is a scalar value, so why not use `=`?

Comment: As for the problem, why were the results you got not what you desired?

Comment: I want result that the result is equivalent to 'SELECT * from @table  where Inscode ='1' 
AND     LocId IS NULL
AND     effdate='2023-02-01 00:00:00.000'  '

Comment: On 2012 you can do `WHERE Inscode =@InsuranceCode AND EXISTS (SELECT LocId,effdate INTERSECT SELECT @LocationIds, @EffectiveDate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing a `NULL` value and you want to compare `NULL` to `NULL` you need to check both values are `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT Inscode,
       LocId,
       effdate
FROM @table
WHERE Inscode = @InsuranceCode
  AND (LocId = @LocationIds OR (@LocationIds IS NULL AND LocId IS NULL))
  AND (effdate = @EffectiveDate OR (@EffectiveDate IS NULL AND effdate IS NULL));
```

If you are on SQL Server 2022 (or an Azure hosted service), you could also use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```
SELECT Inscode,
       LocId,
       effdate
FROM @table
WHERE Inscode = @InsuranceCode
  AND LocId IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @LocationIds
  AND effdate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @EffectiveDate;
```